# What has happened to the file when I entered "mv file.txt ../"?

Tags: files, directory, rename, symlink

I wanted to move 'file.txt' one folder up, but instead of `mv file.txt ../file.txt` I entered `mv file.txt ../`.

Now the file is gone and I didn't get any error message. So it seems <s>the</s> some action was done successfully. But what happened here?

I have backups, so at least that's no problem. But I'd like to understand what I did and if I changed anything or if this file magically disappeared.

Comment: Try `ls ../file.txt` from the same directory.

Comment: @depquid: Oh, there it is. Why can't I see it with `ls` in the parent folder?!

Comment: Did you follow a symlink to get to one of the directories?  Sometimes goofy/unintuitive things happen when working with symlinked directories.

Comment: @depquid: Yeah, the directory where the file was originally placed is a symlink in my home directory.

Comment: You're real issue here is the symlinks and how `cd` and `mv` behave differently when dealing with them.  I've created an answer which addresses that.  You should probably also add info to your question to reflect this factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file was moved to the *actual* parent directory of the one you were in, rather than the parent directory of the symlink you followed to get there.  By default `cd` behaves differently than `ls` or `mv` when encountering `..`.  `cd` just goes up the path, effectively reverse-following symlinks, whereas the others go to the actual parent of the directory they are in, regardless of how you got there.

Imagine a directory tree like this (`~` is the home directory and `shortcut` is a symlink to `maindir/subdir`):

```
~
├── maindir/
│   └── subdir/
│       └── file.txt
└── shortcut -> maindir/subdir/
```

If you simply `cd` to `~/shortcut` then `ls` will show `file.txt`, and `pwd` will show `~/shortcut`.  **However**, while the output of `pwd` is correct according to the symlink you followed to get there, you are actually ("physically", if you will) in `~/maindir/subdir`.  `ls` and `mv` are aware of this, so `mv file.txt ..` will move `file.txt` to the actual parent directory: `~/maindir`, rather than `~` as you expected.

You can get `cd` to behave like the others by using the `-P` switch.  So if you are in the directory you originally ran the `mv` command from (`~/shortcut`) and run `cd -P ..`, it will take you to the *actual* parent directory (e.g. `~/maindir`), and you will be able to find `file.txt` there with a simple `ls file.txt`.  (You can also get to the actual current directory with `cd -P .`.)

Answer (score 3):

`mv file.txt ..` and `mv file.txt ../file.txt` have exactly the same effect. There is a subtle distinction in `mv`:

- If the last argument is a directory (here `..`), you can enter several sources, and they are moved to the destination with the same name(s)
- If the last argument is not a directory (is a file or doesn't exist), the *single* source is moved there.

So, if dir is a directory:

```
mv file1 file2 file3 dir  # Moves the files there
mv file dir               # Moves one file
mv file dir/newname       # Moves file, new name
mv file newfile           # Just renames
```

Comment: You missed a few spaces for the code block at the end there, but I'm not allowed to make edits less than six characters.

Answer (score 2):

`mv file.txt  ../` is a completely legitimate command: you told the kernel to move a file's name to the parent directory of the current directory.  `file.txt` should not have disappeared, it should still appear in the parent of whatever directory you issued the command.

It's possible that circumstances will modify what happens.  For example if `../file.txt` already existed, its contents are now those of `./file.txt`, and whatever `../file.txt` previously contained got deleted.